# Gast 3/4 HP Rotary Vane Pump Diagram Assistance

Tags: motor, rotary, vacuum

[image]I was hoping to get some input on how to interpret this wiring diagram for this 3/4 HP dual voltage vacuum/compressor pump.

I'm new to this, and all of the wiring diagram tutorials I see appear different than the one I have on the side of this motor. If I am reading it correctly, I am thinking line 1 and 2 will either reverse the motor direction. when I open it I see other leads not mentioned in the diagram. I am curious if that means they are not relevant to this motor? Like #5, since it is single phase it makes sense in my mind swapping the lines on the screw nuts would change motor direction. Green is still for ground I believe of course.

The plan is to use it for a vacuum table, and wire it up to a vac switch.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a coincidence, I just installed one of these myself at my workplace!

Swapping the line inputs on a single-phase motor will have no effect; the rotation direction is determined by the way the windings are configured (it's almost certainly what's called a shaded-pole motor).

Convention is that the terminal with the unplated brass or copper screw is the one that gets the live wire (black, if you're in north america. I'm unfamiliar with wiring colors elsewhere.), and the nickel-plated (silver) one is the one that gets the neutral (white in north america), but swapping them won't change functionality. It may have safety problems, though, so I suggest you don't.

If you're plugging it in to a low-voltage AC supply (100 to 115 V AC at 60 Hz, or 100 to 110 V AC at 50 Hz), don't touch the white or brown wires and just wire up the line input and ground. If you're plugging it into a high voltage AC supply (208 to 230 V AC at 60 Hz, or 220 to 240 V AC at 50 Hz), pull the white and brown wires off the terminals they're attached to, plug the white one in where the brown one is now, and stick the brown one into that little plastic holder at the bottom left to keep it out of the way (it should be electrically unconnected in this configuration, I believe).

The purple and blue wires visible in the background are part of the motor's internal wiring, and shouldn't be messed with. Just leave them where they are.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now. It was originally wired with the brown where the white was, so I switched it for low voltage.